# get xargs to run a command once for each input instead of once with every input

Tags: find, xargs

I thought I could run the following

```
find ./ -iname "*\.mkv" | xargs -d "\n" ffprobe -show_streams -i
```

to get codec information for each file, but it appears xargs is trying to pass every file name found to ffprobe instead of running ffprobe once with each input.

when run i get this error

> Argument './Canadian.Bacon.1080p.mkv' provided as input filename, but
> './The Big Short.(2015)/The Big Short (2015) Remux-1080p.mkv' was
> already specified.

Comment: Can you try `xargs -L 1 ffprobe -show_streams -i` instead?

Comment: That seems to almost do what I want. ffprobe is splitting on spaces now Argument 'Mule.1080p.(2018).mkv' provided as input filename, but './The' was already specified.

Comment: i think this one does what I want find ./ -iname "*\.mkv" 2>/dev/null | xargs -L 1 -I {} ffprobe -show_streams -i "{}" | grep codec_name | head -n 1

Answer (score 2):

To run one invocation per file found, you'd be better advised to use the `find` command's own `-exec` capability directly:

```
find ./ -iname '*.mkv' -exec ffprobe -show_streams -i {} \;
```

---

Really the whole point of `xargs` is to pass multiple arguments per invocation. You can make it run a single argument by adding `-n 1` (or `-L 1` in the case that the delimiter is a newline)

```
find ./ -iname '*.mkv' | xargs -d '\n' -n 1 ffprobe -show_streams -i
```

or

```
find ./ -iname '*.mkv' | xargs -d '\n' -L 1 ffprobe -show_streams -i
```

Adding an explicit replacement string like `-I{}` will also work, simply because `-I` *implies* `-L 1`. As well, if you're already using `-d '\n'` to prevent filenames from being split on spaces and tabs, you may as well go the whole hog and allow for filenames to contain newlines, by changing the delimiter to the null character:

```
find ./ -iname '*.mkv' -print0 | xargs -r -0 -n 1 ffprobe -show_streams -i
```

FWIW if you're using `find`, you usually don't need `xargs` even if you *do* want to pass multiple arguments per invocation - there's an alternative form `{} +` that does that for you:

```
find ./ -iname "*.mkv" -exec somecommand {} +
```

Comment: find ./ -iname "*.mkv" -exec ffprobe -show_streams -i {} + produces Argument './Canadian.Bacon.1080p.mkv' provided as input filename, but './The Big Short.(2015)/The Big Short (2015) Remux-1080p.mkv' was already specified. which makes me think it's not calling once per filename

Comment: @Aaron I added the note about `{} +` for completeness - it is specifically for running multiple files per command. You should be using the first command I posted (with `{} \;` at the end).

Comment: @Aaron you probably should specify `-type f` or it may trigger on directories containing `.mkv`